# Multiple actions for single UIButton in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton

** When a button is clicked in my view, I want two text fields and another button(remove). If I pressed again the same action to be repeated up to 5 times. and if I clicked the remove button the two text fields has o remove and below text fields has to come up*

```
-(IBAction)addBusiness:(id)sender
{
    txtprovName2 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    [txtprovName2 setFrame:CGRectMake(13, 410,94, 30)];
    [txtprovName2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtprovName2 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    txtprovName2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    txtprovName2.placeholder=@"";
    txtprovName2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
    [testscroll addSubview:txtprovName2];

    txtprovEmail2 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
    [txtprovEmail2 setFrame:CGRectMake(121, 410,92, 30)];
    [txtprovEmail2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtprovEmail2 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    txtprovEmail2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    txtprovEmail2.placeholder=@"";
    txtprovEmail2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];

    [testscroll addSubview:txtprovEmail2];

    btnRemove1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnRemove1.frame = CGRectMake(220, 410,80, 30);
    [btnRemove1 setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRemove1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
    btnRemove1.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    [btnRemove1 addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(btnRemove1Clicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

how can i proceed for repeated action for same button thank for help

Comment: you want to call this function 5 times on single click

Comment: no after first click if i again clicked the button then omly the function has to perform

Comment: just manipulate tag value..

Comment: how to remove textfields

Comment: [yourTextfield removeFromSuperView];

Comment: how to move below textfields up if i deleted middleone

Comment: set your textField frame again ...[yourTextField setFrame:..]

Comment: while removing iam facing a problem

Comment: if i deleted in sequence only it is working properly if i add two ties andif idelted it is not working

Comment: you have to make your own logic for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the tag property of button; so inside your IBAction method

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        // perform your 1st functionality 
        button.tag = 2;   //To perform 2nd functionality

    }
    else if (sender.tag == 2) {
        // perform your Second functionality
        button.tag = 3; //To perform 3rd functionality

    }
    else if (sender.tag == 3) {
        // perform your 3rd functionality
        button.tag = 1; // To perform 1st functionality
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: shall i need to initialize the tag value

Comment: but while removing iam facing a problem bcoz the below textfield has to come up

Comment: No, you need to just set the button.tag = Value, for the functionality you want to perform in that context...

Comment: After you remove the text field, just change the tag property of button accordingly

Comment: i set the tag value at starting of button clicked operation again it is setted to 1 ans it became infinite loop

Comment: @Sivakrishna: I have edited answer, have a look. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: but how it will enter in to first if condition

Comment: Simply set button.tag = 1; while you initialise your button

Comment: i set the tag value after belo statement. UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

Comment: so when i click the button second time it is again initailsed to 1;actually my button is not programatical in xib file

Comment: but while adding the text fields only iam facing problem . UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; it has to be declared locally.so i initalize the tag value 1

Comment: my button is not programatical in xib so it is not accepting void type

Comment: if i clicked the button then only two text fields have o create from second time. but without clicking it is happened

Comment: i am facing a problem while removing. the user may delete a any point of time like after adding two text fields. but i have done after adding 5 textfields only give me some idea while removing

Comment: Stay away from tags, they'll bite you in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it by tags. You will save alot of memory and will work fine.

Comment: plz give me some idea regarding tags

Comment: Shekhar Gupta gave a good example of buttons by tag. Always use tags for save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Or u can use this methods..

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

& later use

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

This will solve your problem. I hope.